# Show that $\frac {(\mathbb Z/p)[x]}{(x^2)}$ is not isomorphic to $\frac {(\mathbb Z/p)[x]}{(x)} \times \frac {(\mathbb Z/p)[x]}{(x)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given in the question that $\frac {(\mathbb Z/p)[x]}{(x^2)}$ has only one maximal ideal.

So my thinking for this is that   $(\mathbb Z/p)[x]$ is an integral domain.

Now my original thinking was to use Chinese Remainder Theorem as I thought the $\gcd(x,x) = x$ which means they are not coprime so they can't be isomorphic.

I have a secondary thought of showing that   $\frac {(\mathbb Z/p)[x]}{(x)}$ has one maximal ideal, therefore its product $\frac {(\mathbb Z/p)[x]}{(x)} \times \frac {(\mathbb Z/p)[x]}{(x)}$ will have two maximal ideals, but I am not sure whether this is appropriate too.

Comment: The ideal $\;\langle x^2\rangle\le\Bbb F_p[x]\;$ , with $\;\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ , is not prime since $\;x\cdot x\in\langle x^2\rangle\;$ , yet $\;x\notin\langle x^2\rangle\;$ , and thus the ideal cannot be maximal, either.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for your answer :) Like I semi get what you mean, but not 100%. Also are there flaws in my arguments?

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't understand why, just because it isn't prime, means it can't be maximal

Comment: Because any maximal ideal in a commutative unitary ring is also prime...

Comment: Isn't $\frac{(Z/p)[x]}{(x)}$ isomorphic plainly to $Z/p$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh right, I did know that, but I was thinking about ti wrong. Also, is what I put in the question a good argument?

Comment: @DanielMcElroy How can it be if you're arguing that $\;\langle x^2\rangle\;$ is a maximal ideal?!

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, I've actually misinterpreted the question. I have edited the question. So if you want to take a look now

Comment: @JeanMarie Yeah it is, but how does this help me answer?

Comment: @DanielMcElroy Your new "also $\;\Bbb F_p[x]/\langle x^2\rangle\;$ must be a field" is unjustified...and, in this case, wrong...again, since that'd imply $\;\langle x^2\rangle\;$ is a maximal idea, which it is not.

Comment: @DonAntonio Okay, didn't notice that. Thanks for answering the question though. At least I now know that $<x^2>$ is not a maximal ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to show the assert.

The hint is to look at the maximal ideals of the product. Note that a product of two nontrivial rings will always have at least two distinct maximal ideals. Indeed, if $A$ and $B$ are nontrivial rings, choose $I$ and $J$ maximal ideals in $A$ and $B$ respectively. Then $I\times B$ and $A\times J$ are distinct maximal ideals in $A\times B$.

The ring $(\mathbb{Z}/p)[x]/(x)$ is nontrivial, because it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p$.

On the other hand, the ideals of $(\mathbb{Z}/p)[x]/(x^2)$ are in bijection with the ideals of $(\mathbb{Z}/p)[x]$ containing $x^2$: these are only $(x^2)$ itself, $(x)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/p)[x]$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2)$ has a nonzero nilpotent element, whereas

$\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z[x]/(x)\times\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z[x]/(x)\simeq\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$, a product of fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to look at this question, maybe longer but that show what an isomorphism would "concretely" look like, and why it cannot work.

- The product in the ring $A:=\frac {(Z/p)[x]}{(x^2)}$ has the form $(a+bX)(a'+b'X)=aa'+(ab'+ba')X \pmod{X^2}$.

Thus, this ring is isomorphic to $(Z/p \times Z/p, +, * )$ where

$$\tag{1}(a,b) * (a',b') = (aa',ab'+ba')$$

- whereas $B:=\frac {(Z/p)[x]}{(x)} \times \frac {(Z/p)[x]}{(x)} \equiv Z/p \times Z/p$ has the "classical" multiplication rule:

$$\tag{2}(a,b) \times (a',b') = (aa', bb')$$

Clearly (2) cannot be assimilated to (1).

Let us be more precise by a reasoning by contradiction.

Let us assume that a ring isomorphism $\varphi$ exists between $A$ and $B$.

This isomorphism could be transfered, through the following diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}
\alpha \begin{CD}
A @>{\varphi}>> B\\
@VVV  @VVV \\
\mathbb{Z/p}\times\mathbb{Z/p} @>{\psi}>>\mathbb{Z/p}\times\mathbb{Z/p}
\end{CD}\beta$$

into this one:

$$\beta \circ \varphi \circ \alpha^{-1}=:\psi:(aa',ab'+ba')\mapsto(aa',bb')$$

Thus, we would have in particular, taking $a=a'=1$, for all $b, b'$:

$$\tag{3}\psi(1,b+b')=(1,bb').$$

The fact that such an isomorphism exists is impossible for different reasons.

Here is a basic proof that the impossibility is of a serious nature: $\varphi$ is not even well defined.

Here is why. Due to (3), we could write:

$$\psi(1,0)=\begin{cases}\psi(1,(p-1)+1)=(1,p-1)\\\psi(1,(p-2)+2)=(1,2(p-2))\end{cases}$$

The contradiction comes from the fact that in general $p-1 \neq 2(p-2) \pmod{p}$ i.e., $p \neq 3 \pmod{p}$, thus a same element can have more than one image.

(I leave as an exercice the proof of the contradiction for the case $p=3$).

The impossibility of the existence of such an isomorphism $\psi$ yields the impossibility of the existence of isomorphism $\varphi$.

Comment: I don't understand very well what do you mean by $\psi:(aa',ab'+ba')\mapsto(aa',bb')$, but this should be $\psi((a,b)*(a',b'))=\psi((a,b))\times\psi((a',b'))$ which is quite different from what you say.

Comment: If you name the vertical arrows (which are isomorphisms, thus bijective) in my diagram: $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\psi$ is unambiguously defined by $\psi=\beta \circ \varphi \circ \alpha^{-1}.$

Comment: Strangely enough, it seems that only using that $\psi$ is a homomorphism you find it. The elements of $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_p$ don't look like $(aa',ab'+ba')$. As you said below: "I don't understand your argument".

Comment: Thank you for your comments (and also your judicious remark about pinging). By doing this rather "heavy" detour, I wanted to escape critics for a non rigorous approach (I thought exactly as you: "the product elements  $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_p$ don't look like $(aa',ab'+ba')$"). But there is maybe a shorter way that I haven't seen. I am not a specialist in abstract algebra. Btw, I will be out for a certain time (1:30 Central European Time, time to go to bed...).

Comment: Can @Daniel McElroy give also his degree of understanding of this proof ?

Comment: It's trivial to show that $\varphi$ can't be injective: $\varphi((0,1))\times\varphi((0,1))=\varphi((0,1)*(0,1))=\varphi((0,0))=(0,0)$. But $(a,b)\times(a,b)=(0,0)\implies(a^2,b^2)=(0,0)\implies(a,b)=(0,0)$, so $\varphi((0,1))=(0,0)$, a contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

I would simply show you can't create a bijection that satisfies the properties to make the two isomorphic. $\Bbb{Z}_p [x] \big/ \langle x^2 \rangle$ will have polynomials of a greater order, so you cannot construct said bijection.

Comment: I don't understand your argument.

Comment: It's the same as yours ... just worded instead if showing the whole argument. Since the bijection needs to be constructed as such to form an isomorphism between the two, which you showed is not possible.